# Extracting count from where clause

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table of movie reviews:

```
MovieID  UserID Rating

72        64817   5
238       4984    4
167       48176   2
37        19841   1
122       987981  2
48      and so on....
129
143
27
177
47
201
220
12
247
```

If I specify a particular movieID, I know how to display all userID's that rated that movie, along with their rating.

My question: **If there are no reviews submitted by any users, how do I display a message saying so?** If there are no reviews, how do I capture this characteristic?  I tried many things (Working with GUI in C#):

```
sql = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(1) AS num 
                     FROM Reviews 
                     WHERE MovieID = '{0}'", textBox1.Text);

            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = db;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;

object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
int numReviews = System.Convert.ToInt32(result);

    if (numReviews == 0)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("No reviews");
    }
        else
        {
          //I display them. Got this part
         }
```

If result is supposed to be a number (count(1)), why cant I assign to an integer variable and test that?

When I debug this code, I get error exception:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NewMovieNoReview' to data type int.

on this line

```
 result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Update: Silly mistake!! After printing what was in the string, MovieID= NewMovieNoReview instead of an ID! Thanks to Erik for "Examine what is in sql after the call to String.Format()"!
-resolved

Comment: What is not working?  What value does `numReviews` have when you think it should be zero?

Comment: You can simplify your SQL to `SELECT COUNT(1) AS num FROM Reviews WHERE MovieID = '{0}'`.  Using COUNT(1) rather than COUNT(*) provides a slight performance improvement.

Comment: If MovieID is an integer, you should not have the single quotes around the parameter.  Updating my answer.

Comment: Ah good point. However, removing the quotes now gives error Invalid column name 'NewMovieNoReview'. I never say its a column though. NewMovieNoReview is a new movie I added, with no reviews

Comment: Please post the exact SQL statement you are running (what is in `sql` after calling String.Format), and post the structure of the Reviews table.

Comment: @EricJ. Actually COUNT(1) is just translated to COUNT(*) in sqlserver2008, so there is no performance gain

Answer (score 2):

The error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

is SQL complaining about the syntax of your SQL command.

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS num FROM Reviews WHERE MovieID = {0}
```

Note: No single quotes around {0} if MovieID is an integer.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NewMovieNoReview' to data type int.

You did not get an `int` result back because there was an error executing the SQL statement.

NOTE:

Rather than trusting whatever input is in `textBox1.Text`, you should be using a [parameterized query](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/).  Otherwise, a mean user could enter into that textbox `;DELETE TABLE Reviews`.

http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: How do I find out why the error occurs? I used your command instead which gave me the conversion error

Comment: Examine what is in `sql` after the call to `String.Format()`.  Run that SQL statement in SQL Server Management Studio.